# I want to define property that takes argument like this " Text1.Attributes["onfocus"]" here Attribute is an property of Text1 object takes argument

Tags: c#

I want to define property in c# that takes argument like this " Text1.Attributes["onfocus"]" here Attribute is an property of Text1 object takes argument

Answer (score 1):

C# does not support parameterized properties.

Instead, you need to make a class with an indexer that takes those parameters, then make a property that returns an instance of that class.

For example:

```
class AttributesCollection : ... {
    public Something this[string name] {
        ...
    }
}
class TextBox {
    public AttributesCollection Attributes { get; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks SLaks to rly...I now understands that property doesn't takes argument instead use indexer for it..okkkkk..